# Build a numpy sums array from a dictionary with cluster and indices in a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, sum

I have one dictionary with cluster number as keys and matrix's indices as values; and one matrix with float64 values.

The goal is to produce an array of sums with values in the array corresponding to indices in the dictionary.

```
K_Index = {0: [(0,0),(1,1),(1,2)],
           1: [(1,0)],
           2: [(0,2),(2,1),(2,2)],
           3: [(0,1),(2,0)]}

W_Matrix = np.array([[0.34,1.22,-0.56],
                      0.95,-1.45,1.02],
                      -0.02,0.43,1.61]])

Sum_Goal = np.array([-0.09,0.95,1.48,1.20])
```

I found 2 solutions but they are too slow for my program.
I'm working with a 300x785 matrix and 200 keys in the dictionary.
This is the best solution I found and it took ~110ms to complete.
I'm searching for something around < 10ms.

```
def my_solution(d_idx,m_wei,clusters):
    ret = [0 for x in range(clusters)]
    for k,v in d_idx.items():
        for i in v:
            ret[k] += m_wei[i]
    return ret

my_solution(K_Index,W_Matrix,4)
```

EDIT: For now, every solution you provide are slower than mine.
I need a 10x speed up, but I think it's not possible.

Comment: "I found 2 solutions but they are too slow for my program.": you're not showing your solutions, nor do you explain what "too slow" means: 2x too slow, 10x, 100x too slow?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Could you please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I just edit the post with my solution and the time i want to achieve

Comment: Could there be repeated tuples for a key, like `0: [(0,0),(1,1),(1,2),(0,0)]`?

Comment: @Divakar nope, indices are unique

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1**

Here's one way -

```
In [207]: s = np.r_[W_Matrix.shape[1],1]

In [208]: W1D = W_Matrix.flat

In [210]: [W1D[np.dot(k, s)].sum() for k in K_Index.values()]
Out[210]: [-0.08999999999999986, 0.95, 1.48, 1.2]
```

**Approach #2**

Alternatively with `concatenation` -

```
In [242]: vals = K_Index.values()

In [243]: cut_idx = np.r_[0,[len(k) for k in vals]].cumsum()

In [244]: idx = np.concatenate(list(vals))

In [245]: np.add.reduceat(W_Matrix[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]], cut_idx[:-1])
Out[245]: array([-0.09,  0.95,  1.48,  1.2 ])
```

Comment: Both solutions are slower than mine